# How to modify Firefox config (pref.js) using Powershell

Tags: powershell, firefox

Goal: Edit the `pref.js` Mozilla Firefox file with new values remotely using PowerShell:

- Edit the PS script to be able to find the right path in all system
  regardless if the folder name under its profile is different.
- (optional) This script should also work on a remote system.

My idea is the following: Lookup for a directory under `%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\` that has a directory that ends with `.default`. If this directory was found: Search for the file `pref.js` and modify the entry `user_pref("network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris"*`.

Below is what I have so far:

```
$FFProfileDir = %APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\XXXXXXXX.default\pref.js
$data = foreach($line in Get-Content %APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\XXXXXXXX.default\pref.js )
{
    if($line -contains 'user_pref("network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris"*')
    {
        $line -replace '*' , 'user_pref("network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris", ".xxx,.xxx,.xxx");'
    }
    else
    {
        $line
    }
}
$data | Set-Content $FFProfileDir
```

Comment: so ... what is your Question? it looks like you have the code working ... i am confused. [*blush*]

Comment: My code is incomplete and it is not working as intended. the path where the firefox drops the pref.js file is "%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\XXXXXXXX.default\pref.js" [hence XXXX is always a different name in every system]

Comment: please add to your Question the real _question_ ... how to find the file. [*grin*]

Comment: Yes, it is a composite question.
Scope: It is to be able to edit the pref.js Mozilla Firefox file with new values

However, in order to do that you can say that are few dependencies
1 - Edit the PS script to be able to find the right path in all system regardless if the folder name under its profile is different
2- (optional) edit the script to affect not just my system but a remote system Mozilla FF pref.js config

Comment: it is _generally_ a good idea to ask a _narrowly focused question. my personal method would be to ask two Questions so as to keep things tightly focused. i will post my Answer to the "how to find the file" idea in a few minutes. [*grin*]

Comment: thanks. this is my first post.

Comment: you are welcome! [*grin*] please take a look at my Answer. i think it solves your "find the profile.js" problem.

Answer (score 0):

the following will grab the profile dir that has `.default` in the name. then it will join that with the target file name, store it, and finally display it. [*grin*]

```
$TopDir = "$env:APPDATA\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles"
$FileName = 'prefs.js'

$DefaultProfileDir = (Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $TopDir -Directory).
Where({
    $_.FullName -match '\.default'
    }).FullName

$FullFileName = Join-Path -Path $DefaultProfileDir -ChildPath $FileName

$FullFileName
```

output ...

```
C:\Users\[MyUserName]\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\[RandomStuff].default-1511033268061\prefs.js
```

there is another way to get that info. the `Profies.ini` file lists the current "default" profile in standard `.ini` format.

Comment: @NelsonBaez - kool! glad to know that it works as needed. [*grin*]

Comment: I will create another post for the replacement (line) issue.

Comment: good! i will keep an eye out for it ... but may be offline for the remainder of the day.